# How to reset gSettings Key appropriately?

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, gsettings

Being a stupid individual and going beyond what I should in trying to play with Ubuntu, I was trying to figure out better scaling when running 17.10 on my Pixel 2. So I tried to enable Fractional Scaling in gsettings, via the following terminal command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

I thought I could figure out how to reset it back to normal afterwards (screen is extremely blurry after enabling) but...

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

isn't doing it. Am I misunderstanding what the SCHEMA : KEY system is supposed to be, or is there something else that could be causing this problem? Greatly appreciate any help or insight, learning experience here.

Comment: I know this is old but this is expected behavior when enabling fractional scaling -- see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI. In particular "Note: Enabling fractional scaling can result in blur for legacy applications using XWayland, even if only integer scales are used, because the rendering method changes."

I just came across this information myself after some applications were blurry when switching from an X session w/o actual fractional scaling in use (integer only). Resetting the experimental features per below fixed up the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need...

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter experimental-features
```

See

```
gsettings reset --help
```

Also, I don't know how blurry your screen is, but a good graphical tool to use is Dconf Editor.  Install it using:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then you can launch Dconf Editor, navigate to this key, and click on the "Use default value" switch. (Remember to click the check-mark to apply your change).

[image]

Comment: You're awesome, appreciate the help! Especially the heads up on the visual editor, not as command line savvy as I'd like to be yet. Cheers!

Comment: I'm grateful you answered this several years ago as it saved me in debugging blurry chromium and other applications today when switching from an X session to a Wayland session.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `reset` command did not do anything. I did two other things:

1. run `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "[]"`
2. Deleting the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

After a reboot, I finally did not see any of the fractional scaling and blurry fonts